# ImageView onClick method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity `MyActivityListView` and her xml file is this http://pastebin.com/B2thprhT.

The activity does nothing to special , when we click on a row calls another activity passing elements. The rows of this xml are build using this other xml file  http://pastebin.com/H321gRP8.

In the activity associated ad the first xml file on the `onCreate()` method its present this row: `listView.setAdapter(new MyListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext()));` and the `MyListViewAdapter` is made in this way

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<TestTable> testTableArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public MyListViewAdapter(/*ArrayList<TestTable> testTableArrayList,*/ Context context) {
//        this.testTableArrayList = testTableArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        this.databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        this.testTableArrayList = databaseHelper.getValues();
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * Ritorna il numero degli elementi presenti nell'ArrayList
     * @return numero di elementi nell'ArrayList
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//        return 0;
        return testTableArrayList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Restituisce l'oggetto in posizione position
     * @param position = posizione dell'oggetto che verra' restituito
     * @return oggetto in posizione position
     */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
//        return null;
        return testTableArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_single_row_list_view, null);

        TextView zero = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtIdOnCustomView);
        TextView uno = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrimoValoreOnCustomView);
        TextView due = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSecondoValoreOnCustomView);
        TextView tre = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTerzoValoreOnCustomView);

        TestTable temp = testTableArrayList.get(position);

        zero.setText(String.valueOf(temp.getId()));
        uno.setText(temp.getVal1());
        due.setText(temp.getVal2());
        tre.setText(temp.getVal3());

//        TextView uno

        return row;
    }
}`
```

As you see, in the second xml file is present an `ImageView` that is clickable, but I don't understand where insert the method associated at the click because if I insert that method on `MyListViewAdapter` class they return an error, if I insert on `ActivityListView` class they return error.
Thank at all and forgive me for my english, it's the first time I ask something in english :)

Comment: Just use findViewById() to get a reference to your ImageView like you did with the TextViews and set an OnClickListener in code.

Comment: where I place findViewById() method? In the ActivityListView class? If I place the code in onCreate method of ActivityListView I have this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.phate.formazioneandroid1.formazioneandroid1/org.phate.formazioneandroid1.formazioneandroid1.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: .... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Same place where you get the TextViews from the same layout.

Comment: It run! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `findViewById()` to get a reference to your `ImageView` like you did with the `TextView`s and set an `OnClickListener` in code. Do this in the same place where you also get your `TextView`s.